# in signin the method gettext must be called from ui thread error

Tags: gettext

I'm trying to create a login for an application. However I have a problem.

This is my code:

in this code there is an error in the getText() in the android studio
actually m  creating a login page with the help of the JSONParsing of web API, the login detail sync from the web api

```
public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    EditText user, pass, email, mobile;
    private Button  mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //si lo trabajan de manera local en xxx.xxx.x.x va su ip local
    // private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/cas/register.php";

    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://abc.demo.xxxxxxxxx.xxx/xxx";

    //ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etmobile);



        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new CreateUser().execute();

    }

    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }




        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            String mobile = mobile.getText().toString();
            String email = email.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List params = new ArrayList();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        REGISTER_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Registering attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Registering Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass EditText values as args in the Async task.

```
String[] params = {user.getText().toString(),
        pass.getText().toString(),
        mobile.getText().toString(),
        email.getText().toString()};

new CreateUser().execute(params);
```

You can play with the UI elements only in classes that run in UI thread. Activity or fragments etc.